# PHP how to echo an image and text file from each subfolders as a table

Tags: php, html, include, echo

I'm totally new to PHP and not an Advanced web developper but I really like to learn. My problem is the following: I want to make a projects page which would show every projects located in subfolders. In clear, that page would include a thumbnail and a two lines description (in a text file) from each folder to display it as a table and on which a user could click to reach the right project page. Here is the code I am presently stuck with:

```
<?php      
$dir = "*/";
$images = glob($dir."main.jpg" );
$myFiles = glob($dir."description.txt");
$fh = fopen($myFiles, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, 5);
fclose($fh);

foreach( $images as $image ):
echo '<div class="projects"><div class="projects-img-container">';
echo" <img class='projet-img' src='". '/projects/' . $image . "'/>";
echo '</div><div class="project-description">';
foreach( $myfiles as $myfile ):
echo $theData;
endforeach;
echo '</div>';
endforeach;
echo '</div>';
?>
```

description.txt as follow:

```
Gold Collection
Deck 1
```

Any help would be appreciated, as for the moment the images are showing fine, but no text is displayed. Then would also come the link to the respective folder...

Should look something like this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjwX7.jpg

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Misspelling: `foreach( $myfiles` ought to be `foreach( $myFiles`. Notice "Files" is capitalized where you glob it. Show an example what you expect to get from globbing the `description.txt` files. And then what's with the `$fh = fopen($myFiles, 'r');`? What do you expect to do with the filehandler `$fh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the comments & code within the modified script below for suggestions along with the ways I've implemented those suggestions...

```
<?php      
$dir = "*/";
$images = glob($dir."main.jpg" );
/* This doesn't work because fopen() can't take an array
* $myFiles = glob($dir."description.txt");
* $fh = fopen($myFiles, 'r');
* $theData = fread($fh, 5);
* fclose($fh);
*/
echo '<div class="projects">'; // I think you meant to put this outside the loop
foreach( $images as $image ) {
   echo '<div class="projects-img-container">';
   echo" <img class='projet-img' src='". '/projects/' . $image . "'/>";
   echo '</div><div class="project-description">';
   $dn = dirname($image);
   # $myFiles = glob($dn."/description.txt"); // don't think we need to glob() this
   $fh = fopen($dn."/description.txt", 'r');
   $theData = fread($fh, 5);
   echo $theData;
   fclose($fh);
   /* Not sure it makes sense to loop $myfiles - only 1 description.txt can
    * exist in any one directory, right?
    * foreach( $myfiles as $myfile ):
    *  echo $theData;
    *}
    */
   # Whatever you want to do with the directory link would be done with $dn here.
   echo '</div>';
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: Peter, this seems to work except that text in .txt file is limited to 5 caracters (which I can change without problem) and that it is all displayed in one line... Any way to follow line breaks as in the file?

Comment: I just copied your `fread(...)` so you can easily fix that as you said. For line breaks you will need to replace the newline char with `<br />`, probably using `echo nl2br($theData)`.

Comment: n12br is working great! Thank you! Now how could I add a link to the entire div so that it redirects to the project folder? I added a div called "projects" at the beginning of the foreach loop so that each project is well wrapped

Comment: Check out the `<a>` html tag and see if it can be applied to an entire div. Meanwhile, if this answered the question you posed, please do mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Ok for the link, I found it! Simply used echo "<a href='".$link_address."'>Link</a>"; For the rest I know how to extend that <a> to the entire div through css. Thank you so much for your help! That was so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

After review this seems to work well for me. thanks to you Peter!

```
<?php      
$dir = "*/";
$images = glob($dir."main.jpg" );

echo '<div class="projects-container">'; 
foreach( $images as $image ) {

$dn = dirname($image);

echo '<div class="projects">';
echo '<div class="projects-img-container">';
echo" <a href='".$dn."'><img class='projet-img' src='". '/projects/' . $image . "'/></a>";
echo '</div><div class="project-description">';

$fh = fopen($dn."/description.txt", 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, 5);
echo" <a href='".$dn."'>".$theData."</a>";
fclose($fh);
echo '</div>';
echo '<div style="clear: both"></div>';
echo "</a>";
echo '</div>';
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```